# JDBC incompatibility error

Tags: java, jdbc, ant, java-7, java-6

I have a legacy code written in older version of java. I am trying to compile the code and generate an .ear file using ant. The java version i am using is jdk7/jdk6 as java home . 
On executing the ant script, I am getting following error

```
Compiling 20 source files to C:\views\kroger\kroger\of_platform\build\oneforce\classes\ra
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.4
C:\views\kroger\kroger\of_platform\sdk\src\java\ra\com\workscape\connector\wedb\
JdbcConnectionImpl.java:81: error: JdbcConnectionImpl is not abstract and does not     override abstract method getNetworkTimeout() in Connection

public class JdbcConnectionImpl implements JdbcConnection {

C:\views\kroger\kroger\of_platform\sdk\src\java\ra\com\workscape\connector\wedb\
JdbcDataSource.java:78: error: JdbcDataSource is not abstract and does not override abstract method getParentLogger() in CommonDataSource

public class JdbcDataSource
```

I am assuming this error is because of certain jars not compatible with newer jdk version.
This works good when I use jdk1.4/1.5 .. Pls let me know if i need to take any latest version of jar.. The database used is oracle and i am using ojdbc14 for compilation of the database java code.

Its kind of important as we have to decide which version of java we need to use.

Thanks

Comment: What is fully qualified class name of JdbcConnectionImpl and CommonDataSource?

Comment: My question is about exact name of classes that were probably changed. I am surprised because Sun usually hold backward compatibility. If you provide this name I can take a look. But I do not want to guess the class. Simple googling did not provide answer.

Comment: JdbcConnectionImpl and JdbcDataSource  is a customised class but as you can see in the logs above the two class they inherit are import java.sql.Connection and Interface javax.sql.CommonDataSource but the actual class is javax.sql.DataSource; .. Pls advise if you have any inputs on this and i am using jdk1.7 to compile now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java 1.7 has introduced few new methods in `CommonDataSource` & `Connection` interfaces. The ones for which you are seeing the error are:

[getParentLogger()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/CommonDataSource.html#getParentLogger%28%29)

[getNetworkTimeout()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getNetworkTimeout%28%29)

Also, keep in mind that there are more new methods in Java 1.7 than the above two stated ones.

If you want to use Java 1.7, then your custom classes, JdbcConnectionImpl & JdbcDataSource (or their super classes) should implement the new methods defined by `Connection` & `CommonDataSource`, respectively.

Comment: yes let me try that and see if it works.. thanks for the advise.. i was assuming the same that ..it would be tough for other methods to be implemented

Comment: Thanks for the advise.. though there were many methods that i needed to create dummy methods for .. but i am not able to compile the code via ant.. thanks alot

Comment: did you mean "now able to compile the code via ant"??

Comment: Yes sorry for typing it wrong.. i was able to compile the code via ant and build was successful. but i said there were many methods i needed to overide